# How do I keep an element that fills the window centered?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, layout

How do I keep the canvas in the **[this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yymkLytq/embedded/result/)** centered at all times (including when the scrollbars appear) when the window is resized? The canvas element should always fill the window.

I tried playing around with settings like `left`, `margin-left`, etc. (including negative values) but to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you wanted?

This is a refactored version of your code that resizes the canvas to the smallest dimension of the window (width or height) on window resize. It also sets the `display` of the canvas to `block` and uses `margin: 0 auto` to center it.

Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BideoWego/90ks9reo/7/).

**UPDATE 1** I've refactored with comments to show where to change the code to resize the canvas to the largest dimension between the window height and width.

**UPDATE 2** I've refactored to fit the canvas so the crosshairs are always centered by setting the width and height to the exact window.

I've also updated the CSS to remove all padding and margins.

The canvas is redrawn on `window.onresize`.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

function setSize() {
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  //var size = (h > w) ? h : w;   //<<<< resize to largest between height and width
  //var size = (h < w) ? h : w; //<<<< resize to smallest between height and width
  //canvas.width = size;
  //canvas.height = size;
  canvas.width = w;  //<<<< exact resizing to width
  canvas.height = h;  //<<<< exact resizing to height
}

function draw() {
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.strokeStyle = 'red';
  context.moveTo(canvas.width/2, 0);
  context.lineTo(canvas.width/2, canvas.height);
  context.moveTo(0, canvas.height/2);
  context.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height/2);
  context.stroke();
}

setSize();
draw();

window.onresize = function(e) {
  setSize();
  draw();
};
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! I'm actually looking for the canvas to resize to the *largest* dimension of the window, so that it always covers it.

Comment: @user1667423 I've updated my answer to choose the largest dimension, does that do what you expect?

Comment: Thanks! It centers well when the window is large, but it still seems to not work when it's made small. I think I might have to use the window.scrollTo function or something.

Comment: @user1667423 I believe I found what you're looking for, in order to center the crosshairs you have to set the canvas to the exact window dimensions AND remove padding and margins from all elements.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `overflow: hidden;`?

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/yymkLytq/2/)**

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, my aim is not to hide the scrollbars but to have the canvas centered when the window is resized (essentially to make the scrollbars centered at all times).

Comment: not sure what you mean.  in the fiddle, the center of the cross is in the middle at all widths.

Comment: When the scrollbars appear, the canvas ceases to be centered and is stuck at the top left instead.

Comment: aha, i see what you mean.  on larger screens when the canvas is taller than the screen height, you still want the height centered.  So, your js needs to get the difference of the canvas height and the window height divided by 2, then scroll that amount.

Comment: That sounds promising! I tried adjusting the coordinates in scrollTo with window.innerWidth (and corresponding heights) but couldn't get it working properly. How can I get the extrinsic (i.e. CSS) canvas width, as opposed to the intrinsic one (100px)?

Comment: I think using scrollWidth might work (it includes the full scrollable area, not just the visible portion).

Comment: i think height is your only issue, not width

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like 
    canvas{
    position: fixed;
    top: -500px;
    }

Answer (score 0):

To make the canvas resize with the page, try adding a window resize listener:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.width = window.innerHeight;
});
```

If you want to remove margins so the canvas fills the entire page, try adding the following CSS to your page:

```
body {    
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After much fiddling, I think I figured it out. Here's the [**working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/yymkLytq/8/) ([fullscreen version](https://jsfiddle.net/yymkLytq/8/embedded/result/)). I ended up using the following loop:

```
function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    window.scrollTo(
        document.documentElement.scrollWidth/2 - window.innerWidth/2, 
        document.documentElement.scrollHeight/2 - window.innerHeight/2
    );
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

which automatically scrolls the window to the middle of the entire scrollable area (including the non-visible portions) minus half the size of the viewing area itself.

Thanks to everyone for your help!